# Regex to read specific file format in Java

Tags: java, regex, file, io, split

I need to read a file with this format:

```
(w,x,y,z),(w,x,y,z), ... ,(w,x,y,z);
```

All on one line.

//edit:

I eventually will need to do this on files like the following as well:

```
(w,x,y,z_1 ... z_n),(w,x,y,z_1 ... z_n), ... ,(w,x,y,z_1 ... z_n);
```

so simply reading past 3 commas is not going to cut it.

My plan is to read the whole file into a String using the Scanner class, then splitting it up in an array of (w,x,y,z) parts and then splitting that up into the actual w, x, y and z. Eventually the data in the file would end up in a list of objects something like:

```
public class DataBean {
    private String w, x, y, z;
    ...
}
```

I'm having trouble coming up with a regular expression for this though.
I tried

```
String[] allSystems = scanner.nextLine ( ).split ( "),(" );
```

and sure, it cuts the string up, but I feel it's not the most elegant solution. If anyone has a better idea I'd love to hear!

Comment: Frankly I don't think you're going to find a more elegant solution than that.  Elegant != Fancy.  `String[] allSystems = scanner.nextLine ( ).split ( "),(" );` is a very clean way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
String[] allSystems = scanner.nextLine ( ).split ( "(?<=\\)),(?<!\\()" );
```

You get `(w,x,y,z)`, `(w,x,y,z)`, `(w,x,y,z);`

Next, for get `w`, `x`, `y`, `z`,  you can do:

```
String system = "(w,x,y,z);";

String[] data = system.replaceAll("\\(|\\);?", "").split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `line.split("(^\\(|\\),\\(|\\);|,)")` then you will get a String array with each w, x, y, and z as its own element in the array.  The first item in the array will be an empty String, but if you start at index 1 you can easily use this to construct your DataBean objects:

```
String[] data = line.split("(^\\(|\\),\\(|\\);|,)");

List<DataBean> dataBeans = new ArrayList<DataBean>();
for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    dataBeans.add(new DataBean(data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2], data[i+3]);
}
```